# How do I troubleshoot "Error injecting constructor" when adding an amazon S3 repository to ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-s3, elasticsearch-plugin

I've been following the instructions [here](http://tech.domain.com.au/2014/12/elasticsearch-snapshots-backup-restore-s3/)
and I've completed step 1, the installation of the plugin. I'm now trying to add a snapshot by executing the following command in sense:

```
PUT /_snapshot/ElasticSearch
{
     "type": "s3",
     "settings": {
         "bucket": "SomeBucket",
         "base_path" : "ElasticSearch",
         "secret_key": "xxx",
         "acess_key" : "xxx"
        }
}
```

From this I get the following error:

```
{
   "error": "RepositoryException[[ElasticSearch] failed to create repository]; nested: CreationException[Guice creation errors:\n\n1) Error injecting constructor, java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/elasticsearch/common/blobstore/ImmutableBlobContainer\n  at org.elasticsearch.repositories.s3.S3Repository.<init>(Unknown Source)\n  while locating org.elasticsearch.repositories.s3.S3Repository\n  while locating org.elasticsearch.repositories.Repository\n\n1 error]; nested: NoClassDefFoundError[org/elasticsearch/common/blobstore/ImmutableBlobContainer]; nested: ClassNotFoundException[org.elasticsearch.common.blobstore.ImmutableBlobContainer]; ",
   "status": 500
}
```

Any ideas on how to start troubleshooting this? All the information I get in the logs is:

```
[2015-07-13 16:20:40,519][WARN ][repositories             ] [app1050-ela-dacq] failed to create repository [s3][ElasticSearch -d]
org.elasticsearch.common.inject.CreationException: Guice creation errors:

1) Error injecting constructor, java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/elasticsearch/common/blobstore/ImmutableBlobContainer
  at org.elasticsearch.repositories.s3.S3Repository.<init>(Unknown Source)
  while locating org.elasticsearch.repositories.s3.S3Repository
  while locating org.elasticsearch.repositories.Repository

1 error
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.internal.Errors.throwCreationExceptionIfErrorsExist(Errors.java:344)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorBuilder.injectDynamically(InjectorBuilder.java:178)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorBuilder.build(InjectorBuilder.java:110)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorImpl.createChildInjector(InjectorImpl.java:131)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ModulesBuilder.createChildInjector(ModulesBuilder.java:69)
        at org.elasticsearch.repositories.RepositoriesService.createRepositoryHolder(RepositoriesService.java:409)
        at org.elasticsearch.repositories.RepositoriesService.registerRepository(RepositoriesService.java:373)
        at org.elasticsearch.repositories.RepositoriesService.access$100(RepositoriesService.java:57)
        at org.elasticsearch.repositories.RepositoriesService$1.execute(RepositoriesService.java:112)
        at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.InternalClusterService$UpdateTask.run(InternalClusterService.java:374)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor$TieBreakingPrioritizedRunnable.runAndClean(PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor.java:188)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor$TieBreakingPrioritizedRunnable.run(PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor.java:158)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/elasticsearch/common/blobstore/ImmutableBlobContainer
        at org.elasticsearch.repositories.s3.S3Repository.<init>(S3Repository.java:124)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory$1.newInstance(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:54)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:86)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:98)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:52)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:45)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:837)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:42)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:57)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:45)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorBuilder$1.call(InjectorBuilder.java:200)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorBuilder$1.call(InjectorBuilder.java:193)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:830)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorBuilder.loadEagerSingletons(InjectorBuilder.java:193)
```

Note that the version of elasticsearch I'm using is 1.6.0 so the plugin version is 2.6.0. The output of the command 'java -version' is the following:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_45"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b13)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the version of the plugin that had been installed was actually 2.2.0 instead of 2.6.0.

The answer tlrx gives in [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-cloud-aws/issues/151) is the clue.

It's also good to remember to restart elasticsearch after you've updated the plugin